# Amazon Java SQS Client: How can I selectively delete a message from the queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a Spring Boot class the receives messages from a (currently) FIFO SQS queue like so:

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
        .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
        .withMaxNumberOfMessages(numMessages);

Map<String, String> messageMap = new HashMap<>();
try {
    List<Message> messages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();

    if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
        if (messages.size() == 1) {
            Message message = messages.get(0);
            String messageBody = message.getBody();
            String receiptHandle = message.getReceiptHandle();
         // snipped
        }
    }
 }
```

I want the ability to "skip around" messages and find **only a particular message** to remove from this queue. My lead is certain this can be done, but I have doubts. These are my thoughts:

- If I change to a Standard Queue, can this be done?
- I see you have to **receive** a message to get the `receiptHandle` for the `DeleteMessageRequest`.
- But if I receive a message I want processed, not the message to delete, how do I put it
  back in the queue?
- Do I extend the `visibilityTimeout` to let the message be picked up later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes, exactly as you described: receive the message, extract the receipt handle, submit a delete message request
2. yes
3. by simply not doing anything, the message will automatically pop back up in the queue after its visibility timeout expires. Note that even such a basic receive increases the receive counter and may push the message into a dlq depending on your configuration
4. no, extending the visibility timeout will only delay further processing even more

Comment: Ok, so you're saying if I receive the message and don't delete it, it'll be put back on the queue? I could make the visibility timeout something like a minute, and after a minute another listener can pick it up?

Comment: @CNDyson yes. I am however not sure if you can actually decrease the visibility timeout to force the message to be pickup up sooner. The queue has a default visibility timeout than *can* be extended, I am not sure if it can be shortened.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!!